# Socket.io Chat application Shows EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners()

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, socket.io

I am using `socket.io` and `node.js` plus mysql for a private chat application and when i use `socket.on('example', function(data){...});` It throws such error code here.

```
 node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at PoolConnection.EventEmitter.addListener (events.js:175:15)
    at io.on.eventConnection (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/node/server.js:72:15)
    at Ping.onOperationComplete [as _callback] (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:99:5)
    at Ping.Sequence.end (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Ping.Sequence.OkPacket (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:105:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:73:12)
    at Protocol.write (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.Connection.connect (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:96:28)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
```

And my code in 
  Server side:-

```
function fetchMessages(data){
        var sql = "SELECT `msg_descr`,`msg_to` FROM `message` WHERE (msg_to="+data[0].iChatUserId+" AND msg_from="+data[1]+") OR (msg_to="+data[1]+" AND msg_from="+data[0].iChatUserId+") ORDER BY msg_created_date DESC LIMIT 20";
        eventConnection(sql, function(callback, rows){
            if(callback){
                users[data[1]].emit('Release Msg', {messages:rows, selfId:data[0].iChatUserId});
            }
        });
    }

    //when a user is actibe
    socket.on('load Message', function(data, callback){
        var repsondMsg = fetchMessages(data);
    });
```

In client side:-

```
 chatList.click(function(){
        var __this  =   $(this);
            targetData  =   [];
            __userData  =   fetchUserData(__this);
            myId    =   myImage.data('myid');
            targetData.push(__userData, myId);
            socket.emit('load Message', targetData);
            checkExistance(targetData);
    });

    socket.on('Release Msg', function(data){
            $.each(data.messages, function(){
                $.each(this, function(k,v){
                    $('*[data-ichatid="'+data.selfId+'"]').children('.body_cht_box_ind').children('#chats').append($('<li>').text(v));
                })
            });
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

The following link has the explanation. 
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n

> By default EventEmitters will print a warning if more than 10 listeners are added for a particular event. This is a useful default that helps finding memory leaks. Obviously, not all events should be limited to just 10 listeners. The emitter.setMaxListeners() method allows the limit to be modified for this specific EventEmitter instance. The value can be set to Infinity (or 0) for to indicate an unlimited number of listeners."

you can use something like this.

```
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = Infinity;
```

Comment: It's normally better to summarize what the link says than just pasting it. If the link changes, your answer will be rendered useless.